# How to create sound clips when silent?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, voice-recording

So I am writing a program that splits an audio clip up into multiple parts when no sound is playing. So that all the clips created from the sound file only contain sections with sound. How would I accomplish this using Java? I plan on using FLAC, but the program currently supports WAV as well. Would RMS be the best way to determine this? Bonus points for any code.

Comment: I am not signal processing expert, but I think if you do FFT of audio, you may get amplitude of all frequencies near zero, when there is silence.

Comment: That would be absurdly computationally expensive though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can roughly approximate the 'loudness' of a sampled waveform by averaging the squares of the differences between samples n and n+1. This will give you a rough indicator of how "loud" these samples will appear to the hearer.

The method is more sensitive to high frequencies than low ones, thats why it can be off quite a bit if the sound has a very extreme frequency distribution.

For a precise solution you will need to take the FFT approach *and* also correct the extracted frequencies weighting by a model representing the hearers ear (not all frequencies feel equally loud at the same DB level).

Comment: Is there no method that is computationally less expensive?

Comment: @Skylion Depends entirely on your precision requirements. Try the squared delta method. If it is too inaccurate for your requirements there is no bypassing frequency analysis. FFT isn't *that* expensive nowadays (any MP3 encoder needs to do it, and you can real-time encode on a wide range of todays hardware platforms). Edit: Heck even *audio players* do it just for the sake of displaying fancy spectrum analysis. Take a look at JavaMod player (its free and open source): http://www.javamod.de/

Comment: I found this algorithm similar to what you were describing: http://www.source-code.biz/dsp/java/apidocs/biz/source_code/dsp/signal/ActivityDetector.html